# Wordpress - Navbar transparent in home page only

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, navbar, transparent

Im trying to make my navbar transparent in the home page only with full width background and have a red background-color on the other pages like about/contact.

I've search around about it and they make special class for the home page, so home page navbar is different than other pages but I want to do this in wordpress which is all pages have the same header. Any idea how to do it in wordpress?

Comment: Do you mean add a background colour transparent ? to only home page

Answer (score 1):

Any WordPress Homepage contains a body class called `.home`, Which you can use it to access your navbar class, let's say your navbar have an ID called `#navbar`.

You can edit your navbar only on the Homepage using `.home #navbar {}` CSS selector.

Comment: Thank you. It work like a charm! I found the body_class() function